# How to retrieve local variable (geolocation HTML5 and Google Maps API)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck with this problem : I would like to retrieve the position defined by geolocation in order to use it in my calcRoute function as the start point for example, here is the code :

```
function calcRoute(){
   var pos;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
    (
        function(position) 
        {
            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        }
    );

    var start = pos;
    alert(start); // pb here : start is undefined, how could I get the pos value ?
    //...
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try to add a setTimeout, 'cause anonymous function is executed by another thread and you try to get pos value before it's set.

Comment: No, try understanding how asynchronous calls and using callbacks works. Using setTimeout in the hope the result maybe available by then is rather nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you define is a callback function that is called once the location is retrieved.

It will fail for two reasons:

- you don't know if the callback function will be called at all, not to
  say before the rest of `calcRoute` (which is actually extremely
  unlikely as it is asynchronous)
- even if it was called before the end
  of `calcRoute`, the `pos` is in a different scope so you cannot change it
  this way.

You may be tempted to resort to global variables to fix the second issue but you won't be able to fix the first one. Why not put the rest of your code in the callback function?

```
function calcRoute(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
  (
      function(position) 
      {
          var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
          var start = pos;
          alert(start);
      }
  );
```

}

EDIT: more detailed answer to explain why go this route

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcRoute(){
var pos;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
(
    function(position) 
    {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        var start = pos;
        alert(start);
    }
);


//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a callback it will be executed later. but you can devide your code and let it execute.

```
function calcRoute(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
    (
        function(position) 
        {
           var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
           furtherCode(pos);
        }
    );

    }

function furtherCode(position){
    var start = pos;
    alert(start); 
    //...
}
```